# OWIN Context is not initialized properly in ASP.NET Forms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, adfs2.0, owin-middleware

I'm new to OWIN and ADFS. I'm trying to authenticate users from ADFS using OWIN middleware. But when i run the app and perform login, the return `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()` is not initialized properly.

[image]

**owin_middleware_startup.cs**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        ConfigureAuth(app);

    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
        new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, // application cookie which is generic for all the authentication types.
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login.aspx"), // redirect if not authenticated.
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive
        });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
        new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataAddress = "https://adfs-server/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml", //adfs meta data.
            Wtrealm = "https://localhost/", //reltying party
            Wreply = "/home.aspx" // redirect
        });

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    }
```

**login.aspx.cs**

```
    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void loginSSObtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IdentitySignin("administrator");
    }

    private void IdentitySignin(string userName)
    {
        //Create list of claims for Identity
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = true,
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2)
        }, identity);

        //Response.Redirect("/home.aspx");
    }
```

My goal is to redirect to the ADFS login and authenticate the user. Highly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, I had missed the RUN method - [app.Run()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/owin.appbuilderuseextensions.run(v=vs.113).aspx) in the middle-ware. This inserts the extension to the OWIN startup. And executes it for all the requests.
Fix :

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        ConfigureAuth(app);

    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
        new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, // application cookie which is generic for all the authentication types.
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login.aspx"), // redirect if not authenticated.
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive
        });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
        new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "test auth",
            MetadataAddress = "https://adfs-server/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml", //adfs meta data.
            Wtrealm = "https://localhost/", //reltying party
            Wreply = "/home.aspx"//redirect
        });

        AuthenticateAllRequests(app, "test auth");

    }

    private static void AuthenticateAllRequests(IAppBuilder app, params string[] authenticationTypes)
    {
        app.Use((context, continuation) =>
        {
            if (context.Authentication.User != null &&
                context.Authentication.User.Identity != null &&
                context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return continuation();
            }
            else
            {
                context.Authentication.Challenge(authenticationTypes);
                return Task.Delay(0);
            }
        });
    }
```

But if we want to execute the extensions/middle-wares only for some specific path then we can use [app.Use()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions?view=aspnetcore-2.0) this is just one usage of it.

feel free to correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: In my mixed-auth application, it seemed that in some random requests app did not get the identity. I was not able to handle that problem until I found your answer. The AuthenticateAllRequests method saved my life. Thank you a lot!!!